# How to print name and all the roles (if user has more than 1) of a single user separated by comma?

Tags: users, database

I need to print the name of the user in one column and his roles in the second column. If a user have more than one role assigned, roles in the second column should be comma separated. How to do this?

Comment: The simplest answer would be to use Views?

Answer (score 2):

This would go into .tpl.php template file for your page.

```
<?php
  global $user;
  print 'name: '.$user->name;
  print 'roles: '.implode(', ', $user->roles);
?>
```

Or, you can make it a table with 2 columns like so (note, this is html):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td>', $user->name, '</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>User Roles</td>
    <td>', implode(', ', $user->roles), '</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```